# Insertar varios registros a una tabla Oracle de manera optima

Tags: oracle

Estoy intentando insertar varios registros a una tabla de una BD Oracle, y quisiera hacerlo de manera óptima, pero mi script no funciona. A continuación, el script.

Al parecer el error se presenta al tratar de separar con una coma "," los registros a ingresar, pero también he intentado con punto y coma ";" y no funciona:

```sql
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO INT_USER (
        IDSALIDA, NOMBREMSG, IDBLOQUE, FECCREACION, TIPOREGISTRO, NAMEUSER)
    VALUES
       (
     SEAI_IDSALIDA.NEXTVAL, 'VA_NOMBRES_MOVIN', SEAI_IDSALIDA.NEXTVAL, '01/02/24', 'M', 'NOMBRE1'
     ),
     (
     SEAI_IDSALIDA.NEXTVAL, 'VA_NOMBRES_MOVIN', SEAI_IDSALIDA.NEXTVAL, '02/02/24', 'A', 'NOMBRE2'
     );
   COMMIT;
END;
```

Este es el error que obtengo.

> ORA-06550: línea 8, columna 6: PL/SQL: ORA-00933: comando SQL no
> terminado correctamente ORA-06550: línea 2, columna 2: PL/SQL: SQL
> Statement ignored
> 06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
> *Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.

Comment: ¿El campo `FECCREACION` es de tipo DATE? Si es así, estoy seguro que Oracle no va a permitir insertar una cadena a *las malas* en ese campo. Debes [convertir previamente](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Boracle%5D+insertar+fecha) ese valor para que Oracle lo acepte.

Comment: Según recuerdo, Oracle no permite hacer inserciones "masivas" (insertar múltiples filas de una vez). [Salvo que estés usando Oracle 23c...](https://medium.com/@vbalebai/oracle-23c-sql-syntax-for-efficient-data-manipulation-value-constructor-8a776e49f4d)

Comment: Hola Diego podrías decir si la respuesta dada te resultó útil y de haberlo sido marcarla como aceptada, gracias

Answer (score 1):

Usa la siguiente sintaxis:

```
insert all
into nombretabla (columna1,columna2) values ('dato','dato')
into nombretabla (columna1,columna2) VALUES ('DATO','DATO')
into nombretabla (columna1,columna2) values ('dato','dato')
into nombretabla (columna1,columna2) values ('dato','dato')
select * from dual
```

La instrucción **insert all** de **Oracle** se utiliza para agregar varios registros en una sola instrucción **insert**. Los registros se pueden insertar en una tabla o en varias tablas usando un solo comando SQL.

**Referencia**: https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/questions/insert_rows.php